# How to make sure another (new) page is not shown when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

For an assignment I need to have a table made up of JSON data gotten from a server through an AJAX GET request. Also I have to have an extra row to be able to fill in some extra data as well, this data has to be added to the server where I make the AJAX GET request from, I do this by using an AJAX POST request. Both things I have been able to do, so I now have a table which shows the data from the server which you can also add data to as well. But the problem is that when I click the 'submit' button another page will load showing a new URL made for the added data to the server. I only want to add the data to the table, without opening a new page. I have seen some answers on this with <form> tags, but since I have to use a <form> tag I can not use another one inside.
How is this possible by using a <input> tag and button?

This is the code in HTML I have for the row to fill in your own data.

```
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="">
      </td>
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
      <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category" required="">
      </td>
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
      <input type="number" name="amount" min="1" placeholder="Amount" required="">
      </td>
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
      <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location" required="">
      </td>
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
      <input type="date" name="date" min="2000-01-02" required="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

And this is the code in JavaScript for adding the data from the server to the table:

```
$(function func(json) {
  var url = '%url%'
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: '%url%',
    dataType: "jsonp",
  });

  $.getJSON(url,
  function(data){
    var tr;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].category + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].amount + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].location + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].date + "</td>");
      $('#table_one').append(tr);
    }
  });
});
```

I hope I have provided enough information, and thanks in advance for the help :)

EDIT:

I edited the code to solve this, now it looks like this:

```
var url = '%url%

var tabinithtml = '';

function fillTable() {
$('#table_one').html(tabinithtml);
    $.getJSON(url,
        function(data){
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].category + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].amount + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].location + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].date + "</td>");
            tr.sort
            $('#table_one').append(tr);
        }
    });
}

function insertRecord() {
    $.post( url, $( "#form" ).serialize()
    );
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    tabinithtml = $('#table_one').html();
    fillTable();
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        insertRecord();
        fillTable();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this by using this code:

```
var url = '%url%
var tabinithtml = ''; 

function fillTable() { 

$('#table_one').html(tabinithtml);

$.getJSON(url,
    function(data){
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].category + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].amount + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].location + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].date + "</td>");
        tr.sort
        $('#table_one').append(tr);
        }
    });
}

function insertRecord() { 

$.post( url,
    $( "#form" ).serialize()
    );
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

tabinithtml = $('#table_one').html();

fillTable();

$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    insertRecord(); 
    fillTable();
    return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent form submission by using

```
$("form").submit(function(){ return false; });
```

Comment: I have to be able to submit the form, but it should not open a new page showing the URL for the stored data. With this I can't even submit the form, so this is not yet the answer, but thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
return false;
```

before the function ends

For example:

```
function(){
  //all function srcripts
  return false;
}
```

In your case, it should be like this:

```
function(data){
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].category + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].amount + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].location + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + data[i].date + "</td>");
  $('#table_one').append(tr);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: When I add this only data is added in the first row, but there should be four rows. Also the problem still persists :/

Answer (score 0):

you can make sure the form doesn't actually submit to "url given" by preventing the default behavior, but you'll have to do whatever you want with the form using js/jquery

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do your stuff here
    $.ajax(){
        url: '%url%',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {datafromform}
    }.success(msg){
        console.log(msg)
    }
})
```

try something like this, you get echo JSON data on the server side, so in PHP for the results you add:

```
echo $jsonizedData;
die();
```

so in message, now you will have the json data back from the php file

Comment: Using this piece of code I still want to post the data. But then when I add this:
    $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '%url%',
    dataType: "jsonp",

The same problem appears again...

Comment: You can use ajax to post the data after preventing the default behavior of the form.

Comment: Do you possibly have another solution than the one I added in my previous comment? Because with that piece of code the same thing will just happen..